# sitting gesture

Tags: vocabulary

The lady is sitting with her right leg folded and her left leg upright.

Can we use 'upright' and 'folded' for the positions seen in the picture

[image]

Comment: Since she is a lady, it's **her** right leg.

Comment: Question has been edited

Comment: Both legs are bent or 'folded'. _Upright_ would suggest that the leg was sticking up in the air! It's a rather odd position to describe; you could say 'her left leg is drawn up in front of her and her right bent out to the side'.

Comment: I think you mean "sitting **posture**".  A *gesture* is usually done with the hands.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting What about "her knee is upright."?

Comment: @xeesid  No, "her knee is upright" sounds strange and confusing.  But "with one knee drawn up" is more idiomatic and could work; for example, ["He moved to the bed and sat down, settling back against the headboard with one knee drawn up to his chest."](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Deadly_Masquerade/Eg9w-51O8XAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22knee%20drawn%20up%22&pg=PA63&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22knee%20drawn%20up%22)